# Adding max_allowed_packet to my.cnf stops mysql server

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I do Drupal dev work on my Mac using a Homebrew setup for mysql, and on a couple version 6 sites, I get the famous "mysql: server has gone away" error when trying to bring up the status report page.  After doing some searching, I have found that the answer seems to be adding the max_allowed_packet settings to the [mysqld] section of my.cnf.  So, using the my-medium.cnf file provided in the mysql formula, I place it in /usr/local/etc and add

```
max_allowed_packet=65M
```

However, mysql does not like that for some reason.  I run mysql.server restart, and it seems to start, but when I try to run a query in my client, but it tells me there is no connection.  I then try removing the setting from my.cnf and restart, but instead of restarting, I get

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/username.home.pid)
```

Attempting to reconnect the socket gives me an error saying that either the request times out or unable to connect via the socket (/tmp/mysql.sock in this case).  On the Drupal site, I get a "No such file or directory." message.

Can anyone explain why merely adding this value to my.cns causes such results?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** After examining the my.cnf I was using, I noticed that the [mysqld] section already had max_allowed_packet = 1M.  I removed it and created my.cnf that had only

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

and I still get the same result.  For some reason, mysql doesn't like it when I add or change that setting.

Comment: What other values have you tried? I'd try incrementing it by 1M until it stops working.

Comment: So I modified the value to be 65536 (64 * 1024), and if I do SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'max_allowed_packet', it shows me that value.  However, the phpinfo settings still doesn't show max_allowed_packet, and I still lose the connection when I try to do any modification of user settings in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, it should be a value in bytes in increments of 1024. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet